# Symfony2 - Generate CRUD

Tags: symfony, crud

I am trying to generate CRUD of the entities but i have a few questions, i don't know if it's a normal comportment or an error.

I apply the command :

[image: commande du CRUD]

I am adding the route in routing.yml like asking.

Now, when i am testing this crud , just create party work.

Update doesn't working, it's updateAction :

```
public function updateAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('IFppoGestionPersonnelBundle:TableTest')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find TableTest entity.');
    }

    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
    $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isValid()) {
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('tabletest_edit', array('id' => $id)));
    }

    return $this->render('IFppoGestionPersonnelBundle:TableTest:edit.html.twig', array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    ));
}
```

I don't know why it doesn't add "em->persist($entity)", but if i add this line , it does not update ...

I have same errors with deleteAction.
And when i am creating a new tuple, and back to list , the last tuple is not displaying.

It's maybe an error to the class :

```
IFppo\GestionPersonnelBundle\Entity\TableTest:
    type: entity
    table: tabletest
    fields:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
        nom:
            type: string
            length: 255
            column: nom
        prenom:
            type: string
            length: 255
            column: prenom
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

In log, i don't have any trace of update ...

**[EDIT]** When writing to the log for any errors, return an empty array with *$editForm->getErrors()* and with *$editForm->getErrorsAsString()* return  :

nom:     No errors prenom:     No errors submit:     No errors  [] []

Thanks a lot.

Comment: does it give any exception ?